# implementing a L-L fault in SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, simulink, fault

I have implemented a simple circuit using SIMULINK. The file is in the [following link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipsp3f8lkm6p41v/fault_no_protection.mdl?dl=0) This is a screen photo of the circuit:

[image: system picture]

The circuit consists of only a 240 dc source feeding a 4 ohm resistor. I simulated the circuit for 0.05 sec and assumed that there is a line to line fault at the second 0.02. Then, I plotted the figures of V_source, I_source, I_fault, V_load and I_load. For the fault current, I got the figure as expected which is zero before the fault and very high after the fault.

Also, I_source is 240/4=60 A before the fault and very high after the fault. However, the values for V_source, V_load and I_load are not as expected. they are the same before and after the fault which is not logical.

I don't know why this happened.

I am using MATLAB 2010

Comment: Note that updating to a newer MATLAB might be highly beneficial to attract more answers, since potential answerers will have to take care of compatibility issues.

Comment: Actually, theoretically speaking, the results I got are completely correct. But, we know at the fault, the load voltage and load current will go to very low values because of the high fault current value. Is there a way to implement this idea in SIMULINK ?